# Having trouble saving document to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

so I'm having a really hard time getting the document to save to the database in the case where the product already exists in the cart. I am able to target the item from the database, make changes to it and console output the correct values but in this particular case it wont save the result to the Database. I've tried rewriting it using the updateOne() function and I had little luck. I could really use the help i'm super stuck on this probem. Pics for more info: [Block of code that's not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbeMF.png), [console output that reflects desired change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tILEb.png), [mongoDB document that the changes will not save to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KboB.png).

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

```
router.post('/add-to-cart',[
          auth,
          check('productId','productId is required').not().isEmpty(),
          check('quantity', 'quantity is required').not().isEmpty()
    
    ] ,   async (req,res) => {
            //checks field validation
            const errors = validationResult(req);
    
            if(!errors.isEmpty()){
                res.status(400).json({errors:errors.array()});
            };
    
            //Takes token from the header
            const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
            if (!token){
                return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'no token, auth denied'});
            }
    
            //decode token and find associated user
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'));
            let userPayload = decoded.user;
            
    
            //build cart object
            try{
                //populate from request body
                const {productId, quantity} = req.body;
                //find User using the payload
                let user = await User.findById(userPayload.id);
                //get the product from db
                let product = await Product.findById(productId);
                //calculate price of item(s) added to cart
                let total = ( quantity * product.price);
    
                //create cart object 
                //Check to see if cart already exists
                let iscart = await Cart.findOne({user:user});
                //there is an existing cart
                *if(iscart){
                    let found = false;
                    for (i=0;i<iscart.orderItems.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(iscart.orderItems[i].product._id.toString() == product._id.toString()){
                            found=true;
                            console.log('found that product!');
                            iscart.orderItems[i].qty += quantity;
                            try{
                                await iscart.save();
                                console.log(iscart); 
                                }
                            catch(err){
                                console.error(err);
                                res.status(500).send('server error');
                            }
                            res.status(200).send(iscart.orderItems[i]);
                            break;
                        }*
                    }
                    if(!found){
                        await Cart.updateOne(
                            {user:iscart.user},
                            {$push:{orderItems:
                                { 
                                product:product,
                                qty:quantity,
                                total:total 
                                }}
                            }
                            )
                            res.status(200).send('product pushed to orderItems')
                    }
                }
                //there isnt an existing cart so we create one
                else{
                    const cart = new Cart({
                        user,
                        orderItems:
                       { product:product,
                        qty:quantity,
                        total:total
                       }
                    })
    
                    await cart.save();
                   
                    res.status(200).send('cart created and saved');
                }
                
                
                
            }
            catch(err){
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).send('server error');
            }
    
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!! When you are updating a nested object inside of a document you have to mark the object as modified so it knows to update it. this line fixed my issue:

```
iscart.markModified('orderItems');
```